# Problema con diseño responsivo fullpage js

Tags: javascript, responsive

Estoy usando la librería Full Page JS y tengo ciertos mediaqueries en css que al ir probando, achicando y agrandando el navegador, funcionan bien, pero cuando uso el emulador de dispositivos del navegador, no usa ninguno de mis mediaqueries, aplica el responsive por defecto de fullpage js.
¿A qué se debe esto? ¿Tendría que cambiar los estilos desde JS? Me darían algún ejemplo, por favor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,
no sé si te ayude o ya lo tengas, pero intenta agregar eso en el head de tu archivo html principal

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Jesus Daniel Pardo Serrato, toda la razón, me tonteé al no fijarme eso, siempre me generaba automático eso, pero esta vez no me fijé y no estaba. Gracias.